Angular v19 pdfMake cannot see its typing
In prep for an angular upgrade I've created a v19 ng instance and installed pdfMake & its typing npm package.
I'm working throught the examples on the pdfMake site and using their code and I'm getting errors
First off getting a ref to the module here
import pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.vfs;

Create a sample definition and pass to the createPdf method. This works with all but simple text.
Define an "margin" or "alignment" into your definition and I get a very long "argument of type" yadda yadda.
If I manually mark-up the alignment declaration with "as Alignment" then it works.
alignment: 'justify' as Alignment,

Its like its not seeing its types.d.ts. I manually updated tsconfig.spec.json with "pdfmake" in it types array. Also, I can right click on the pdfmake import object and "got to type definition".
The types package was showing in the package.json, but not in devDependancies (i moved it) and finially I added the following in tsconfig
    "strict": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

Any ideas.
This works just fine in ng v15.
